# Jaxb unmarshaling return null object

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, unmarshalling, pojo

I have very interesting xml and i am try to convert this xml to pojo. after my jaxb unmarshalling its return empty object.

here is xml:

```xml
<ServiceResultOfArrayOfstringuHEDJ7Dj xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/HotelWeb.SanAdminSite.RestWebApi.App_Data">
    <Data xmlns:d2p1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
        <d2p1:string>1105</d2p1:string>
        <d2p1:string>1111</d2p1:string>
    </Data>
    <Error>
        <Code></Code>
        <Message></Message>
    </Error>
    <InfoMessage></InfoMessage>
    <IsSuccessful>true</IsSuccessful>
</ServiceResultOfArrayOfstringuHEDJ7Dj>
```

My POJO's :

```java
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "ServiceResultOfArrayOfstringuHEDJ7Dj", namespace = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/HotelWeb.SanAdminSite.RestWebApi.App_Data")
public class PostSendLogIdServiceXmlResult {

    private String xmlns;

    @XmlElement(name = "InfoMessage")
    private String infoMessage;

    @XmlElement(name = "Error")
    private Error error;

    @XmlElement(name = "Data")
    private PostSendLogIdData data;

    @XmlElement(name = "IsSuccessful")
    private boolean isSuccessful;

    public String getXmlns() {
        return xmlns;
    }

    public void setXmlns(String xmlns) {
        this.xmlns = xmlns;
    }

    public String getInfoMessage() {
        return infoMessage;
    }

    public void setInfoMessage(String infoMessage) {
        this.infoMessage = infoMessage;
    }

    public Error getError() {
        return error;
    }

    public void setError(Error error) {
        this.error = error;
    }

    public PostSendLogIdData getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(PostSendLogIdData data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public boolean isSuccessful() {
        return isSuccessful;
    }

    public void setSuccessful(boolean successful) {
        isSuccessful = successful;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "PostSendLogIdServiceXmlResult{" +
                "xmlns='" + xmlns + '\'' +
                ", infoMessage='" + infoMessage + '\'' +
                ", error=" + error +
                ", data=" + data +
                ", isSuccessful=" + isSuccessful +
                '}';
    }
}
```

```java
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name = "Error")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class PostSendLogIdError {

    @XmlElement(name = "Code")
    private String code;
    @XmlElement(name = "Message")
    private String message;

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```

```java
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import java.util.Arrays;

@XmlRootElement(name = "Data", namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class PostSendLogIdData {

    @XmlElement(name = "string")
    private String[] postSendLogIds;

    private String _xmlns;

    public String[] getPostSendLogIds() {
        return postSendLogIds;
    }

    public void setPostSendLogIds(String[] postSendLogIds) {
        this.postSendLogIds = postSendLogIds;
    }

    public String get_xmlns() {
        return _xmlns;
    }

    public void set_xmlns(String _xmlns) {
        this._xmlns = _xmlns;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "PostSendLogIdData{" +
                "postSendLogIds=" + Arrays.toString(postSendLogIds) +
                ", _xmlns='" + _xmlns + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

And My Jaxb converting implementation:

```java
 context = JAXBContext.newInstance(PostSendLogIdServiceXmlResult.class);
            Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
 PostSendLogIdServiceXmlResult unmarshal = (PostSendLogIdServiceXmlResult) unmarshaller.unmarshal(new StringReader(response));
```

After this I'm getting new `PostSendLogIdServiceXmlResult` object with empty values.

Can you give me any advice.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the XML again. The namespace is not applied to the `<Data>` element, it is applied to the `<string>` sub-elements. Notice where the `d2p1:` prefix is applied.

Also, the `<Data>` is not a root element, so the entire `@XmlRootElement(name = "Data", ...` annotation is unused, i.e. unnecessary, and it seems to be confusing you, so I recommend removing the annotation from the `PostSendLogIdData` class.

Correct use is:

```java
@XmlElement(name = "string", namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays")
private String[] postSendLogIds;
```

Comment: After remove XmlRootElement annotation from PostSendLogIdData and put name space to postSendLogIds i am still getting same result.(empty model)

Comment: @AygünBozdemir Could be because you're missing namespace from all the elements. You should probably declare the main namespace at the package level, so you don't have to repeat it all over. --- I've found that finding mapping errors like this is much easier when you generate the XML, so you can see how JAXB interprets the combination of annotations given. Once the output matches the input you want to parse, the annotations are a needed and parsing should then work correctly.

Comment: Actually i really didn't get it. :( i already declare a namespace for package level. (@XmlRootElement(name = "ServiceResultOfArrayOfstringuHEDJ7Dj", namespace = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/HotelWeb.SanAdminSite.RestWebApi.App_Data")).

Comment: @AygünBozdemir No, that declared the namespace for that element only. The XML in the question declared a namespace for all elements without a prefix (`xmlns=...`), so **all** the elements except `<d2p1:string>` are in that namespace.

Comment: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><ns3:ServiceResultOfArrayOfstringuHEDJ7Dj xmlns:ns2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays" xmlns:ns3="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/HotelWeb.SanAdminSite.RestWebApi.App_Data"><Data><ns2:string>1111</ns2:string></Data><IsSuccessful>true</IsSuccessful></ns3:ServiceResultOfArrayOfstringuHEDJ7Dj>` i try to fill my model and generate xml and this is the result but i still dont get it what should i do

Comment: I'd recommend you start by reading up on how namespaces work in XML, how they are defined in a schema, and on how namespaces work in JAXB, including how to define the namespace for all the JAXB classes in a package.